# Is there a bug or my error in a custom drawRect() function?

Tags: c, function, graphics

My drawRect() function is behaving as if there is a bug. I am trying to determine if there is a bug in the following, or, if not what I am doing incorrectly.

I am trying to make a function that displays a rectangle on the topscreen.  If the programmer types in "drawRect(3,3)", a 3 by 3 rectangle is created.  Yet, if the programmer types in "drawRect(3,4)", the upper right corner of the rectangle is displayed, and then an infinitely long top.  Could someone help me?  Here is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define SIDES 0xB3
#define TOP_RIGHT 0xBF
#define BOTTOM_LEFT 0xC0
#define TOP_BOTTOM 0xC4
#define BOTTOM_RIGHT 0xD9
#define TOP_LEFT 0xDA

int heightloop;
int widthloop;

int displayrect(int height, int width)
{
printf("%c",TOP_LEFT);
for(widthloop=1;widthloop<width-2;width++)
{
    printf("%c",TOP_BOTTOM);
}
printf("%c\n",TOP_RIGHT);
for(heightloop=1;heightloop<height-2;height++)
{
    printf("%c",SIDES);
    for(widthloop=1;widthloop<width-2;width++)
    {
        printf(" ");
    }
    printf("%c\n",SIDES);
}

printf("%c",BOTTOM_LEFT);
for(widthloop=1;widthloop<width-2;width++)
{
    printf("%c",TOP_BOTTOM);
}
printf("%c",BOTTOM_RIGHT);
return(0);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your loops you should increment `widthloop` and `heightloop` instead of `width` and `height`. Also `widthloop` and `heightloop` should be initialized with 0.

Comment: Thanks!  I guess I'm incrementing the width of the rectangle, therefore the rectangle's width keeps on increasing, just like the problem I was having.

Answer (score 0):

Loops such as this:

```
for(widthloop=1;widthloop<width-2;width++)
```

and:

```
for(heightloop=1;heightloop<height-2;height++)
```

will do nothing when `width <= 3` or `height <= 3`.

Also note that `widthloop` and `heightloop` should really be local variables, although this is not a bug *per se*, just a "code smell".